# integrated Rest API (json) BPMN with React or Angular 8 & typescript ready

Tags: json, angular, reactjs, workflow, workflow-engine

i need a angular or react bpmn library with typescript and rest api service not xml or any thing else. also dont wana pars xml to json.

search a lot about that but I see lot of limitations and cant find bpmn library with json service.

> i need to make a workflow like [this](https://workflowengine.io/demo/designer/) with react or angular
>   that communicate via json with back-end and typescript ready.

Has anyone experience about this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) and [bpmn-engine](https://github.com/paed01/bpmn-engine) together. These are server-side technologies.

I don't think you'll find an angular or react library that does this, because these are primarily client-side view rendering libraries.